# Method for reproducing minimal, cartoon-style protein structure visualisation

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, visualization, figure-reproduction

I recently came across a preprint ( [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1101/2024.03.14.585103), [PDF link](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2024.03.14.585103v1.full.pdf) ) that has some figures of protein structures in a style that I have not seen before.  To me it appears easier on the eyes and less noisy than the more traditional 3D models with lighting that "reflects" on a glossy surface.  I am interested in creating similar plots of my own protein structures.

Does anyone recognise this style / know how to generate these plots from a PDB file or similar?

(Extended Data Figure 2, page 20)

[image: Protein cartoon figure]

Comment: see https://ccsb.scripps.edu/illustrate/

Comment: Thanks. Any chance you could put the link with a small explanation as an answer @pippo1980?

Comment: https://ccsb.scripps.edu/illustrate/documentation/

Comment: https://github.com/ccsb-scripps/Illustrate

Comment: I've never used it, so cant really help you out , sorry